# Output complex nested JSON from TreeGrid control flat data

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, nested, treegrid

I am using a TreeGrid JavaScript control from DHTMLX to allow users to input and arrange nested data.  The control only allows access to the data in the TreeGrid via flat rows (you'd think in this day and age it would do JSON...).  The rows contain a rowId, rowIndex, parentId, hasChildren and of course the data itself.

The data input looks like:

[Data input control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hNU4.png)

I need to output (and later read back in from Mongo) nested JSON like the below.

I have experimented with iteration and recursion.  I'd prefer to do it recursively, but I'm getting hung up on adding new nodes to the object accumulating the JSON because property names are repeated throughout the data structure, making obj[key]=(recurse here) seemingly impossible.  I need to retain order.  This is probably really simple and I'm missing something.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
{
    "NpcResponses": [{
        "Challenge": "Hello there traveler!",
        "PlayerResponses": [{
            "Keywords": ["hello","hi"],
            "NpcResponses": [{
                "Challenge": "Would you [mind] doing something for me?",
                "PlayerResponses": [{
                    "Keywords": ["mind","sure","ok"],
                    "NpcResponses": [{
                        "Challenge": "Please [take] this bag of sugar to the stable master.",
                        "PlayerResponses": [{
                            "Keywords": ["ok","take","yes"],
                            "NpcResponses": [{
                                "Challenge": "Thank you, you are most kind.",
                                "Event": "QST_BagOfSugar01"
                            }]
                        },
                        {
                            "Keywords": ["no"],
                            "NpcResponses": [{
                                "SetMood": "Disappointed",
                                "Challenge": "Oh well, have a nice day."
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "Keywords": ["no"],
                    "NpcResponses": [{
                        "Event": "Set Mood Disappointed",
                        "Challenge": "Never mind, I'll find someone else to help me."
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: You should give an example of the input data in JavaScript.

Comment: If I am reading your question correctly then you want to output treegrid data as json; if that is correct then have you tried using "tree.serializeTreeToJSON();"?